# Categorial data visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I would like to plot some census data I have into something such as the charts for Educational Attainment or Race & Ethnicity in the picture below (measureofamerica.org). Is there any way to do it using python and matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: You can make something like this with matplotlib.  Please show us what you have tried.  You will get better answers on SO if you have some plausibly working code to start with.  People are happy to help you fix your problems, but are not interested in providing free consulting.

Comment: @ullfoll: you could do something like this in matplotlib, but I think you'd have better luck using a tool that's built for vector graphics, like cairo.  In the picture above, there aren't many graphs (matplotlib's strength) but there are a lot of vector graphics (cairo's).  Either one could take some work. http://cairographics.org/pycairo/

Comment: `matplotlib` has a cairo backend.

Comment: @tcaswell: Of course, but that doesn't help matplotlib generate graphics other than what it was designed to generate.  That is, the cairo backend is great for putting matplotlib type graphics into cairo, but the issue here is that most of the graphics the OP wants aren't of a type that matplotlib generates particularly well.  Used this way, matplotlib would just be an intermediary encumbrance, not a aid.